# Get SO data as JSON/XML?

Tags: feature-request, screen-scraping, android

I've poked around MSO a bit and seen that there's a data dump and some discussion of screen-scraping, so perhaps I sadly already have the answer to my question, but is there/might there eventually be some way to interact with SO from a non-browser in a way that doesn't involve screen-scraping?  I'd like to build an Android app for accessing SO, but screen-scraping is both extra work and extra data...

Answer (score 3):

There's JSON to get the reputation gained on a specific day, if that's any good to you - that's what my reputation tracker uses. URL format:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/rep/[userid]/[from-date]/[to-date]
```

The userid is the numeric one (e.g. 22656 for me). The from-date and to-date are in yyyy-MM-dd format.

Answer (score 1):

There has been discussion in the past (really popular uservoice suggestion) concerning an API that would allow for access into StackOverflow, but nothing so far has come of it.